# RequiredFieldValidator make form not save ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, save, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using a RequiredFieldValidator and the error message that I created shows up but the information still saves. How do I fix this ?

here is the code

```
         <th align="left">RFP EXP:</th>
                <td>                   
                        <GMDP:GMDatePicker ID="rfpExpDatePicker" runat="server" OnPreRender = "rfpExpDatePicker_DateChanged" CalendarFont-Names="Arial" InitialText="Select a Date" InitialValueMode="Null"> 
                            <CalendarDayStyle Font-Size="9pt" />
                            <CalendarTodayDayStyle BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="DarkRed" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <CalendarOtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                            <CalendarTitleStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" />
                            <CalendarFont Names="Arial" />
                        </GMDP:GMDatePicker>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
```

ControlToValidate="rfpExpDatePicker"
 Text="You Must Choose a date before the info will save" runat="server" />

Comment: Do you mean the page posts back while the error message is showing up? Odd. Would you post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you wrapped your button's Click event a valid check?

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    // do something...
}
```

You can't rely on the client side javascript to do the error trapping for you so always implement the server side check.

Comment: NO I haven't and I'm not quite sure exactly how to do that I found the place for the code but am not sure how to place it there